# PCI 164-Pin Design on Altium

Tags: pcb, schematics, altium, cad

[image]

I would like to design a PCB having PCI 164-Pin on that shown at image. Is there any component I can add to schematic on Altium or should I just put some I/O ports on schematic?

Comment: In the past I have done card edge connectors (similar to PCI connectors) by 1) Creating a standard connector schematic symbol, and then 2) Creating a PCB layout with the pads in the right places. I have always done it by hand which gives me more control over it, but that's just my personal preference. Not sure if I should add this as an answer or just leave it as a comment

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Altium Designer comes with some pre-installed template boards, including PCI examples. I don't have Altium on this computer, but I can tell you later how to find the templates on disk.

You can also download the templates online from [Altium Design Content](https://designcontent.live.altium.com/). Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePnWR_F0Ljo) describing how to do that.